# What is the difference between profiles and permission sets in salesforce?

Tags: permissions, salesforce

I know that profiles and permission sets control a user's object- and
field-level access permissions. But I can't recognize when to use profiles and when to use permission sets.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Datamyze above, and I will add that it is not easy to say when to use one or the other, there are no rules, only guidelines.

First you have to be aware of what settings and permissions can we set in Profiles (Pr) and Permission Sets (Ps):

- Apex Class Access (Pr + Ps)
- Apex Page Access (Pr + Ps)
- Application Visibility (Pr + Ps)
- Custom Permission (Pr + Ps)
- External Data Source (Pr + Ps)
- Field Permission (Pr + Ps)
- Login Hours (Pr)
- Login IP Range (Pr)
- Object Permission (Pr + Ps)
- Page Layout Assignment (Pr)
- Record Type Visibility (Pr + Ps)
- Tab Visibility (Pr + Ps)
- User Permission (Pr + Ps)

Then, depending on your requirements, you have to decide what settings are more "global" and then can be kept in a profile that will be assigned to several users with different roles and what settings are more specific for some users. And here, one other thing to take into account, what is the role of the user? (consider the Salesforce's Role object and in real life).

With that information, you will be able to solve the problem as in the example Datamyze used.

If you are already in the situation that you have several Profiles and Permission Sets, and you want to simplify and reduce the numbers, check out this tool "deployPKG" that will allow you to create Excel reports of your profiles, permission sets and even more, get a report comparing them. Having the reports, you will be able to notice the differences very easy. See this post: [Compare Profiles, Permission Sets, Picklists and more](https://www.deploypkg.com/compare-profiles/)

Answer (score 1):

Profiles should be used to provide groups of similar users with the same permissions.  For example, you may have profiles for sales users, sales managers, service users, etc.

Permission sets are useful for providing a specific set of functionality to a user in addition to the permissions provided by their profile.  For example, you may want to grant only a few of your sales and service users the ability to manage dashboards.  In this case, rather than having a special sales profile and another special service profile with the manage dashboard permissions, you would create a permission set with the manage dashboards permission and assign it to those users.

Comment: I faced this question in an interview: What does profile has that permission sets doesn't?